# How to create new pandas column by vlookup-like procedure on another data-frame

Tags: pandas, dictionary, categorical-data

I have a dataframe that looks like this.  It will be used to map values using two categorical variables. Maybe converting this to a dictionary would be better.
[image: Index, and Column names represent possible values taken by two categorical variables in another data-frame]

The 2nd data-frame is very large with a screenshot shown below. I want to take the values from the categorical variables to create a new attribute (column) based on the 1st data-frame.

For example...

A row with FICO_cat of (700,720] and OrigLTV_cat of (75,80] would receive a value of 5.

A row with FICO_cat of (700,720] and OrigLTV_cat of (85,90] would receive a value of 6.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

[image]

Comment: take a look here https://medium.com/importexcel/common-excel-task-in-python-vlookup-with-pandas-merge-c99d4e108988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column labels are the `FICO_cat` values, and your `Index` is `OrigLTV_cat`, this should work:

Given a dataframe `df`:

```
         780+  (740,780)  (720,740)
(60,70)     3          3          3
(70,75)     4          5          4
(75,80)     3          1          2
```

Do:

```
df = df.unstack().reset_index()
df.rename(columns = {'level_0' : 'FICOCat', 'level_1' : 'OrigLTV', 0 : 'value'}, inplace = True)
```

Output:

```
     FICOCat  OrigLTV  value
0       780+  (60,70)      3
1       780+  (70,75)      4
2       780+  (75,80)      3
3  (740,780)  (60,70)      3
4  (740,780)  (70,75)      5
5  (740,780)  (75,80)      1
6  (720,740)  (60,70)      3
7  (720,740)  (70,75)      4
8  (720,740)  (75,80)      2
```

Comment: I have two df's.  The small df has the index values.  And column labels.  The Other df has the FICO_cat and OrigLTV_cat series.  I need to take the values of  FICO_cat and OrigLTV_cat and pass them through the 1st df shown to get a new series.

Comment: What is the relation between the index and column values for the small df, and the FICO_cat and OrigLTV_cat values of the second dataframe?

Comment: OrigLTV_cat has the valules that correspond to the index.  FICO_cat has the values that correspond to the column names in the lookup df.  Is this what you are asking about?

Comment: Yes, I think my code should solve your problem then. You can merge the values from the output onto the second dataframe, if there could be `NaN` values, etc.

Comment: am not trying to get from the 1st df shown to the second.  The Second is a VERY large df with millions of rows.  I want to take the values for  FICO_cat and OrigLTV_cat from the large df and pass them through the indexed df to get a new attribute with the integer values corresponding to the combinations of  FICO_cat and OrigLTV_cat.  Can you show the merge operation too?

Comment: Do you have any elements in the `FICO_cat` or `OrigLTV_cat` columns of your VERY large df that are not contained within the row or column index of the "small df"? If yes, then you need to merge the output of the dataframe I showed you, and your VERY large dataframe to account for `NaN` values. If not, then maybe your VERY large dataframe isnt very large afterall, and this is exactly what you need.

Comment: I have constructed the categorical variables such that there are no NaN values.  Every combination of FICO_cat or OrigLTV_cat will be mapped to the integer values from the small df.